# Pass variable when piping to sudo bash

Tags: bash, bitbucket.org

I try to make a simple command to run a script in my private Bitbucket.
The script need to be run as root, and it will then download more files from the repo, so I need the password for the bitbucket-account.

How do I pass `$bbpass` to `runme.sh`?

```
read -s -p "Password:" bbpass && curl --user myuser:$bbpass https://bitbucket.org/myuser/misc/raw/tip/runme.sh | sudo bash && unset bbpass
```

**runme.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Hello world!"
echo $bbpass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the variable `$1` instead of `$bbpass`.

The `$1` means first argument. So if you pass in two arguments, you can access then with `$1` and `$2` respectively.

Comment: It made the trick, thank you! Just hade to add -s to bash too.

read -s -p "Password:" bbpass && curl --user myuser:$bbpass https://bitbucket.org/myuser/misc/raw/tip/runme.sh | sudo bash -s $bbpass && unset bbpass